# Global instance of a class in C++

Tags: c++, singleton

As the title says.  How would I create an instance of a class that is globally available(for example I have a functor for printing and i want to have a single global instance of this(though the possibility of creating more)).

Comment: This previous question is but one example of a singleton here on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270947/can-any-one-provide-me-a-sample-of-singleton-in-c

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Going to all the effort of making a singleton object using the usual pattern isn't addressing the second part of your question - the ability to make more if needed. The singleton "pattern" is very restrictive and isn't anything more than a global variable by another name.

```
// myclass.h

class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass();
    void foo();
    // ...
};

extern MyClass g_MyClassInstance;

// myclass.cpp

MyClass g_MyClassInstance;

MyClass::MyClass()
{
    // ...
}
```

Now, in any other module just include `myclass.h` and use `g_MyClassInstance` as usual. If you need to make more, there is a constructor ready for you to call.

Comment: Ugh. This will break if MyClass depends on some other global instance being initialised first, since the order of initialisation of globals is "random". Better to use regular class + (create a single instance) factory class.

Comment: @rq: Its not random: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294270/how-do-you-call-a-constructor-for-global-objects-for-arrays-of-objects-and-for#294308

Comment: Random, undefined, cannot be determined at compile time... same difference.

Comment: if I did like MyClass = MyClass() what would happen?

Answer (score 5):

First off the fact that you want global variables is a 'code smell' (as Per Martin Fowler).

But to achieve the affect you want you can use a variation of the Singleton.
Use static function variables. This means that variable is not created until used (this gives you lazy evaluation) and all the variables will be destroyed in the reverse order of creation (so this guarantees the destructor will be used).

```
class MyVar
{
    public:
        static MyVar& getGlobal1()
        {
            static MyVar  global1;
            return global1;
        }
        static MyVar& getGlobal2()
        {
            static MyVar  global2;
            return global2;
        }
        // .. etc
}
```

Comment: According to this logic, std::cout is a code smell as well.

Comment: @rr-: You should read ["Martin Fowlers" book on refactoring](http://www.amazon.com/Refactoring-Improving-Design-Existing-Code/dp/0201485672/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1439219908&sr=8-1&keywords=refactoring+by+martin+fowler).

Comment: @rr-: Or any of the millions of articles on [Global mutable state being bad](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil)

Comment: @rr-: Or watch some of the [Google Talks about Global Mutable state being bad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI)

Comment: I'm not sure how reasons for singletons being bad relate to my observation about `std::cout`. Is `std::cout` bad or not? If it's not bad, why? (Note - I assumed it isn't bad, because if it was, people would have come up with something different.)

Comment: @rr-: Like all globals its a smell. A smell does not mean necessarily bad it means you should take another look to make sure.

Comment: Globals are perfectly fine for many uses. Much more dangerous thing is if they now include non-builtin static variable in the signleton without knowing about static initialization order fiasco.

Comment: @IgorLevicki: The static order initialization problem is easily solved (and is not even a problem (as long as you understand the issue) let a lone a fiasco).

Answer (score 1):

As a slight modification to the singleton pattern, if you do want to also allow for the possibility of creating more instances with different lifetimes, just make the ctors, dtor, and operator= public.  That way you get the single global instance via GetInstance, but you can also declare other variables on the heap or the stack of the same type.

The basic idea is the singleton pattern, however.

Answer (score 1):

Singleton is nice pattern to use but it has its own disadvantages. Do read following blogs by Miško Hevery before using singletons.

1. [Singletons are Pathological Liars](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/17/singletons-are-pathological-liars/)
2. [Root Cause of Singletons](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/25/root-cause-of-singletons/)
3. [Where Have All the Singletons Gone?](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/21/where-have-all-the-singletons-gone/)

Answer (score 0):

the [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and concurrency safe implementation is Scott Meyer's singleton:

```
#include <iostream>

class MySingleton {
public:
    static MySingleton& Instance() {
        static MySingleton singleton;
        return singleton;
    }
    void HelloWorld() { std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; }
};

int main() {
    MySingleton::Instance().HelloWorld();
}
```

See topic IV [here](http://www.research.ibm.com/designpatterns/pubs/ph-jun96.txt) for an analysis from John Vlissides (from GoF fame).

Comment: it ISN'T concurrency safe. In C++ standard, static becomes "initialised" when constructor ends, so each thread that will enter Instance() method at the time of initialisation will cause singleton to be re-created,

Comment: Dmitry Khalatov@ Technically correct. There are several simple solutions. a) Use gcc it has an explicit fix to deal with this (non standard). b) Create the object before any threads c) Use a lock inside the Instance() method.

Comment: I agree with @Dmitry:  until the standard provides a way to deal with the presence of threads, it's unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to allow a singleton but not enforce it so in never hide the constructors and destructors.  That had already been said just giving my support.

My twist is that I don't use often use a static member function unless I want to create a true singleton and hide the constr.  My usual approach is this:

```
template< typename T >
T& singleton( void )
{
   static char buffer[sizeof(T)];
   static T* single = new(buffer)T;
   return *single;
}

Foo& instance = singleton<Foo>();
```

Why not use a static instance of T instead of a placement new? The static instance gives the construction order guarantees, but not destruction order.  Most objects are destroyed in reverse order of construction, but static and global variables.  If you use the static instance version you'll eventually get mysterious/intermittent segfaults etc after the end of main.

This means the the singletons destructor will never be called.  However, the process in coming down anyway and the resources will be reclaimed.  That's kinda tough one to get used to but trust me there is not a better cross platform solution at the moment.  Luckily, C++0x has a made changes to guarantee destruction order that will fix this problem.  Once your compiler supports the new standard just upgrade the singleton function to use a static instance.

Also, I in the actual implemenation  I use boost to get aligned memory instead of a plain character array, but didn't want complicate the example